# How to Get Unique Elements from a DOM Collection in Vanilla JavaScript ES6+

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript function that returns an array of Node or Element, but it contains duplicates. I searched around and found functions to get the unique items of an array, but it seems to work only on strings or simple types, when applying it to the DOM array, it does nothing. I assume it has to do with the items being objects.

Using ES6's Set as some answers suggest doesn't work. Another suggestion uses a filter function to check if the item already has an index in the array. Again, neither works for the DOM objects.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point to how I can remove the duplicates. Thanks in advance!

**Update**

@Kroltan seems to have understood what I mean, but for everyone else, here's a function that returns duplicate nodes:

```
function (
    selector) {
    const children = Array.from(this.parent().children).filter((
        v) => v !== this);

    if (!selector) {
        return children;
    }

    return children.filter((
        v) => v.matches && v.matches(selector));
}
```

If I were to do something like `$("div")`, I will get a lot of duplicates depending on nesting. I want to shrink the returned array of nodes to have no duplicates similar to how jQuery's implementation does it. Here's an example screenshot of my version (1) and jQuery's version (2). I want to get them to match.

[image]

**Update 2**

Figured it out. The `Set` solution works, but I was applying it to the wrong array and so I wasn't seeing the result I was expecting. Now that I'm applying it to the right array, it works, imagine that... :)

Comment: Can you post some example code so we can see what the duplicates are like? I didn't know that an HTMLCollection or a NodeList would ever retrieve duplicate values

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c duplicates on which base?

Comment: I've updated my question to showcase more what I mean/want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those solutions do work. But they work on the principle of referential equality.

**You're probably looking to remove structural duplicates**, (e.g. a bunch of `<br>` elements or whatnot) that's trickier, and you'll have to decide on a criterion for their equality yourself. Something like [Lodash's `uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqBy). (check its source to see how it works!)

Comment: You were right, those solutions do work, specifically the Set option. Turns out that I was applying the Set to the wrong array which was causing my confusion.